# Plot line from open to close

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Currently have some code plotting a line above the open of each day. This plot starts at the correct value but I then get a diagonal line between values. I'm wanting to plot a horizontal line for the whole day instead, so this would be a horizontal line above the open from the initial value continuing until the close before resetting at the new value based on the new open.

There is no option for this on pine script reference manual that i can see so I'm really not sure where to start. I know its possible as I have seen similar things for other indicators so I'm potentially searching the wrong things.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Below is my current code

```
indicator("Jack AVG Hi Low", "Jack AVG HL", timeframe="D")


//user inputs
high_avg_period = input(12, "High AVG Period")

//calculations
avg_high = ta.sma(high-open, high_avg_period)

//plot
plot(close+avg_high, title='AVG High', color=color.green, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_stepline)
```

Below is a screenshot of all three plots as they currently are with diagonal lines between each days open.

Below is  also a screenshot of the open plotted each day as I would like my lines plotted each day. Unfortunately the code is hidden.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhIBq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Wn6.png)

Comment: Can you maybe explain what is happening at the moment and what you want to have with a screenshot?

Comment: A screenshot maybe?

Comment: @vitruvius sorry for the late reply i have been away camping :)  I have edited the post and added screenshots. thanks in advance for any help

Comment: @karatedog sorry for the late reply i have been away camping :)  I have edited the post and added screenshots. thanks in advance for any help

Comment: @JackMahon Pine is a strange beasts so I want to try to rephrase your question :-) You want to work with a chart, that has higher resolution than a Day (say, hourly) and you want to draw a line with the daily open price value until the day closes (and several candles were drawn during the day) and when the next day starts, you want to change the value of the line and continue the same way as the current day was plotted?

Comment: @karatedog yes this sounds correct. So the day opens and a straight line is plotted from the open until the days closes. Then a new plot begins from the new days open. The important thing is the two plots are not connected from close to open. Thanks for getting back to me :)

Comment: Why would you want to avoid connecting the plots? That would be much harder to code as each individual line would be a drawing object. While letting the last price point on the day to be connected with the next days' open would be much easier as you could use `plot()`. On the second thought, I would say that even changing the color of the `plot()` at the last candle of the day to transparent and changing it back to normal color on the first candle of the next day is a lot easier.